# red5 applications on centos

Tags: red5

I want to ask you about building red5 application on centos

I prepare all the files and configurations

```
APP_NAME
        => WEB-INF
           =>lib
           =>src
                => Application.java
           =>classes
                => Application.class
           =>build.xml
           =>red5-web.xml
           =>web.xml
           =>red5-web.properties
           =>log4j.properties
           =>build.properties
```

all is ok the building also ok and make jar file is ok

```
ant build 

ant build 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

but when I restart my red5 server all demos applications and my new application not work

if I make new netConnection I receive this error message :

```
netconnection.connect.failed
netconnection.connect.closed
```

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should first check the log files produces by Red5 in the folder "log" if there are startup or runtime exceptions.
it will be required that you have a minimum knowledge of Java and how to read Java log files in order to be able to implement a solution with Red5.

Answer (score 0):

Red5 can be installed as stand alone server or as a war deployment.

The procedure is to create war deployment of red5 version 0.8(old version). (Lengthy, please bear with me).

Download and install jdk1.6, glassfish2.1 and netbeans 6.5 on linux.

Download "Red5War_0.8.0.war".

I am sharing in the hope that the following may help the community to create a deployable war red5 version 0.8 on glassfish2.1 by following the steps using in Netbeans 6.5:

Step 1: Un-Zip the Red5War_0.8.0.war

Step 2: Create a web project named "red5" in Netbeans

Step 3: Copy the content of "/WEB-INF/classes" of inflated war folder and paste it in "Source Packages" of Netbeans Project.

Step 4: Right Click "Libraries", add "JAR/Folder", navigate to "/WEB-INF/lib" of inflated war folder, select all the dependency jars and Click On "Open" of Netbeans Project.

Step 5: Delete WEB-INF of Netbeans Project (Note : Ignore Warning/Error).

Step 6: Delete META-INF of the inflated folder.

Step 7: Copy the remaining content ("/WEB-INF/classes" and "/WEB-INF/lib") of the inflated folder to "Web Pages" of Netbeans Project.

Step 8: Open the following ports in the firewall TCP/843,TCP/1935,TCP/5229,TCP/5080

Step 9: Run the project

Step 10: Deployable war file "red.war" is created in the Netbeans Project Folder(../NetBeansProjects/red5/dist/)

Similarly,  you can create new projects...

Best wishes!

Arumugam A.V

p.s:Please share your findings in creating new version(1.0, 1.0.1, 1.02) war deployments using new version netbeans, jdk on new version glassfish server(3.x).